# HIGH CONTRAST CRASH OF TEX STUDIO

Tags: incompatibility, revision-control

**HIGH CONTRAST CRASH OF TEX STUDIO**
Several months ago, I customized Tex Studio to bring up disability assistance in the form of high contrast.
Unfortunately, Tex Studio provided as well a singular, non removable option which tends to obscur written lines. Retweaking has not help. Even instructing STudio to go back to standard features, uninstalling, repairing, downloading new versions have not helped.
How do I get back to the Standard Studio again?

Comment: Guess for Windows 10: Maybe look at the **AppData** folder `C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Local` a folder with a name similar to `TeXStudio` and **delete it**. You may have to change the File Explorer setting, so that "hidden" folders are visible.

Comment: In addition, you may report this behavior on the **official issue tracker**: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues